# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHTR_trades.csv'

Tags: python, ubuntu

I would appreciate help with this simple code:

```
import csv
with open('CHTR_trades.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    chtrreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ', quotechar = '|')
    for row in chtrreader:
            print ', '.join(row)
```

I am receiving error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/PycharmProjects/practice/reader.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open('CHTR_trades.csv','rb') as csvfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHTR_trades.cs
```

I checked the location of the file from the terminal and it is in the correct folder:

```
peter@peter-HP-G60-Notebook-PC:~/PycharmProjects/practice$ ls

CHTR_quotes.csv        CHTR_stdev.csv   graph.py      plot.py       practice.py
CHTR_quotes.short.csv  CHTR_trades.csv  matplotlibrc  practice1.py  reader.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that Python does not have enough information to find the file.  You can fix the problem by simply supplying the full path<sup>1</sup>:

```
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/PycharmProjects/practice/CHTR_trades.csv'),'rb') as csvfile:
```

Or, you could use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) and change Python's current working directory:

```
from os import chdir
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/PycharmProjects/practice/"))
with open('CHTR_trades.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    ...
```

Either way, you need to give Python some more information as to where the file is.

---

<sup>1</sup>In both of the code examples above, [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) is used to expand the `~` in the filepath into your home directory.

Comment: User's home directory (usually `/home/username`, `/Users/username`, `C:\Users\username`)  See [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)